# fltk installation on Mac 10.8.3

Tags: xcode4, terminal, installation, osx-mountain-lion, fltk

I'm struggling with `fltk` installation on my Mac, I'd like to run in on `Xcode 4`. After downloading the file and unzip it and trying to follow the instructions:

---

```
 2.3  Configuring FLTK
-----------------------

Stay in your FLTK source-code directory. Type:

  autoconf

Now configure your FLTK installation:

  ./configure

ADVANCED: type "./configure --help" to get a complete list of optional 
configurations parameters. These should be pretty self-explanatory. Some
more details can be found in README. 

To create Universal Binaries, start "configure" with these flags:
  ./configure  --with-archflags="-arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64"
:END_ADVANCED
```

---

First of all, when i try to run `autoconf` I get:

```
-bash: autoconf: command not found.
```

Also the `./configure` command, like this `dhcp-10-201-207-151:fltk-1.3 user$ ./configure`, I get:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried followed many tutorials on the web, which most of them are outdated, it didn't work for me. Apparently,there is another way to install it using Macports which I also failed to apply.

If somebody could show the steps to install `fltk` and run it on `Xcode` in a easier manner, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: You'll have to install autoconf yourself, just to start with: https://gist.github.com/jellybeansoup/4192307

Comment: Install Apple Developer tools first.  You can get them with xCode or by downloading directly from developer.apple.com.  There are other ways to solve that problem but that's probably the easiest and if you want to keep going with FLTK you'll be glad you have them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use autoconf or the options you mention.
You can compile FLTK on OS X like this, if you have Xcode 4 and Command Line Tools installed:

```
./configure CC=clang CXX=clang++
make
sudo make install
```

At least that worked fine for me...

I've also built it on OS X with Xcode, but then you have to go to the

```
fltk-1.3.2/ide/Xcode4
```

Directory, and open the FLTK.xcodeproj file with Xcode, then choose "Demo" as the build target and "Build for Archive". Then you can manually move the files to /usr/local/ if you want, or as a framework in /Library/Frameworks.

I'd go with option 1 though.

Comment: Thanks.  I was missing the configure options, and was going nuts trying to figure out what the problem was.  FLTK 1.3.3 just built fine for me using the above (after updating Xcode).