# Installing FLTK for Xcode 7 on OX 10.11

Tags: xcode, fltk

My background, I am currently self learning on chapter 12 of Bjarne Stroustrup, Programming Principles and Practice Using C++, 2nd Edition.

So I have been trying to install FLTK.

**First** attempt.

From my what i found online i needed to install it using homebrew and then access it from Xcode. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879961/setup-xcode-and-fltk), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ppp-public/jNTx7tNh7z8/qQZbowrSlv0J) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fltkgeneral/ohvAwPXU5lk). However Homebrew was having problems with connecting to a particular website.  I would share the error but now when i run homebrew I get a different error (since i updated xcode during my second attempt).

> `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in`'
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `'

update:

reinstalled homebrew. ran brew install fltk:

> brew install fltk
>
> fltk: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on OS X
>   versions newer than Yosemite due to an upstream incompatibility.
>   Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

**Second** attempt.

So I tried "fltk-1.3.2/ide/Xcode4" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560901/fltk-installation-on-mac-10-8-3) and in the comments [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fltkgeneral/ohvAwPXU5lk). After opening tar file like a zip I following the Readme for OSX. The following section is the most relevant section:

> ### 4.3  Configuring FLTK
>
> Launch Xcode. Open the project file in
>
> .../fltk-1.3.xxxx/ide/Xcode4/FLTK.xcodeproj
>
> There is nothing else to configure.
>
> ### 4.4  Building FLTK
>
> Use the "Scheme" pulldown menu to change the active target to "Demo"
>   and  "My Mac 32-bit" or "My Mac 64-bit". Select "Build for" ->
>   "Running"Run" from  the "Product" menu to create all libraries and
>   test applications.

This resulted in a failed install. So i tried updating XCode from 7.1 to 7.3 and tried again. The install still failed.

The problems with the install.

1. all of the files in Products are red(and not located in finder) except fltk.framework, fltk_png.framework and fltkzlib.framework .
2. numerous errors red and yellow see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPbGr.jpg) for most of them.

   **Third** attempt.

I unzipped a new folder of FLTK, and ran make. This resulted in the following errors.

> fl_line_style.cxx:38:13: error: elaborated type refers to a typedef
>   static enum CGLineCap fl_quartz_line_cap_ = kCGLineCapButt;
>
> ```
>       ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPath.h:33:26:
> ```
>
> note:
>
> ```
>   declared here typedef CF_ENUM(int32_t, CGLineCap) {
>                      ^ fl_line_style.cxx:39:13: error: elaborated type refers to a typedef static enum CGLineJoin fl_quartz_line_join_ =
> ```
>
> kCGLineJoinMiter;
>
> ```
>        ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPath.h:25:26:
> ```
>
> note:
>
> ```
>   declared here typedef CF_ENUM(int32_t, CGLineJoin) {
>                      ^ fl_line_style.cxx:113:15: error: elaborated type refers to a typedef   static enum CGLineCap Cap[4] = {
> ```
>
> kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapButt,
>
> ```
>       ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPath.h:33:26:
> ```
>
> note:
>
> ```
>   declared here typedef CF_ENUM(int32_t, CGLineCap) {
>                      ^ fl_line_style.cxx:115:15: error: elaborated type refers to a typedef   static enum CGLineJoin Join[4] = {
> ```
>
> kCGLineJoinMiter, kCGLineJoinMiter,
>
> ```
>           ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPath.h:25:26:
> ```
>
> note:
>
> ```
>   declared here typedef CF_ENUM(int32_t, CGLineJoin) {
>                      ^ 4 errors generated. make[1]: * * * [fl_line_style.o] Error 1 make: * * * [all] Error 1
> ```

So now I am stuck. Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I removed enum from the following lines:

```
    static enum CGLineCap fl_quartz_line_cap_ = kCGLineCapButt;
    static enum CGLineJoin fl_quartz_line_join_ = kCGLineJoinMiter;
```

To:

```
    static CGLineCap fl_quartz_line_cap_ = kCGLineCapButt;
    static CGLineJoin fl_quartz_line_join_ = kCGLineJoinMiter;
```

Also these lines should look like this:

```
      static  CGLineCap Cap[4] = { kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapButt,
                               kCGLineCapRound, kCGLineCapSquare };
      static  CGLineJoin Join[4] = { kCGLineJoinMiter, kCGLineJoinMiter, 
                                kCGLineJoinRound, kCGLineJoinBevel };
```

Then make should work.