# fltk display image weird in macos

Tags: c++, linux, macos, display, fltk

I have a program in which `fltk` was used, it works well on the Linux platform. Yesterday, I purchased a macbook pro and copied the code onto it. At first it gave an error that it could not find the X11 lib. Then I clearly indicated where the lib is, and the code can be complied successfully. However, it cannot display the images correctly, it is totally white. No image, even the right click menu content is white when I press the right mouse button.

I think it is caused by the fltk library, but I have no idea where it is going wrong. This is my first time to code under macos, please give some suggestion and your thoughts.

Comment: You need fltk build for Mac OS X, not GNU/Linux build you are using. You can install mac version of fltk using MacPorts or build it from source code like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560901/fltk-installation-on-mac-10-8-3

Comment: Your question is not about programming, it is about Linux/MacOS. I suggest to ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com, or on https://apple.stackexchange.com .